# Sharding for 512 tables of the same structure (1 database) with doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, sharding

I would like to shard a big table with more than 150 millions lines.
I want to break this table in a set of 256 or 512 same table structure.

There is an example, a table docs with 150 millions lines will become docs_00, docs_01, ... docs_ff for 256 shards.

I have found sharding in Doctrine but for database horizontal sharding, not for tables.
https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.8/reference/sharding.html#generic-sql-sharding-support

How did you handle this issue with Doctrine?

Comment: Do you have 256 servers?  And your one computer can't handle it now?  That is what "sharding" is all about.  Perhaps you meant "partitioning"?  That is likely to not provide any performance benefit.

Comment: Please describe the application _and_ why you think splitting up the table would be beneficial.

Comment: With big table we have big indexes who can be very slow until we use PARTITION.

Comment: In our case we calculate a hash like md5 of a unique entry and we get the two first chars to determinate which table to ask for request.

The goal of sharding tables like this it to have smal number of lines in each tables so we can make LIKE or MATCH requests without delay.

But we are on the way to consider a search engine for this type of requests and make only exact requests on one big table, who is fast with good optimisation of queries and index. @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing *only* "point queries" (that is, looking up one row by a unique index), there is nothing better than having an index on that column and having all the rows in a single table.  No `LIKE`, no `MATCH`, no multiple tables.